# Use stored procedure to insert some data into a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create stored procedure that inserts some data into my table, but I'm getting some errors like

> Invalid Column name

For all the columns that I specified in my stored procedure. I have an IDENTITY COLUMN called ID which increments by one each time record is inserted. I also have some other columns in the table but they can be null. Here is my stored procedure and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here.

```
USE MYDB
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Test]
  @myID bigInt,
  @myFirstName nvarchar(50)
  ,@myLastName nvarchar(50)
  ,@myAddress nvarchar(MAX)
   ,@myPort int

AS 
BEGIN 

 SET NOCOUNT ON; 

  BEGIN 

insert into MYDB.dbo.MainTable (MyID, MyFirstName, MyLastName, MyAddress, MyPort)
values(@myID, @myFirstName, @myLastName, @myAddress, @myPort)

  END 

END
GO
```

Here is the table definition:

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MainTable]    Script Date: 01/03/2013 11:17:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MainTable](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MyID] [bigint] NULL,
    [MyFirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MyLastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MyAddress] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MyPort] [int] NULL,
    [MyZipCode] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [CompName] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Show your table definition.

Comment: If it's an identity column you just exclude it from your column list. You may want to add a try/catch as well.

Comment: i just added the table definition.  i also added the Identity column but still getting the same error.  thanks for your help

Comment: Does `dbo.MainTable` definitely exist in the `MyDb` database?

Comment: Instead of an image of the columns in the table, could you add a CREATE TABLE script to show more information?  Easiest way to get that is to right click on the table in Management Studio, and select SCRIPT Table as Create to Clipboard from the menu.

Comment: @user1858332 if you run the `INSERT` on its own with the values you are passing into the stored proc does it work?

Comment: i just updated the table definition per your request.  Yes, the table exist in the database.  thanks again

Comment: What are the values you are trying to pass into the stored proc?  I just created your table, procedure and received no error messages.

Comment: How are you inserting rows? From database or from any web/window app? Where is this error thrown?

Comment: I've just created the table and procedure using your scripts and I can't reproduce your issue... I can see you explicitly stated the database name in your procedure "MYDB.dbo.MainTable"... Can it be that you have two databases with this table and procedure and then you run your procedure on one database and there is and old version of MainTable in MYDB?

Comment: Do you get the error when you try to run the proc, or when you're creating it?

Comment: **do you really need 8 byte `bigint` IDs?** you know that a 4 byte `int` is good enough for values up **`2 BILLION`**.  do you honestly think your application will ever get thet many rows?  you are wasting critical RAM when you cache your data and indexes.

Comment: I used your code and create SP successfully.
May be mistaken at execution time.
Please check the column and value you are taking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the table definition to have an IDENTITY column e.g. IDENTITY(1,1) then don't include MyId in your INSERT INTO statement.  The point of IDENTITY is it gives it the next unused value as the primary key value.

```
insert into MYDB.dbo.MainTable (MyFirstName, MyLastName, MyAddress, MyPort)
values(@myFirstName, @myLastName, @myAddress, @myPort)
```

There is then no need to pass the @MyId parameter into your stored procedure either. So change it to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Test]
@myFirstName nvarchar(50)
,@myLastName nvarchar(50)
,@myAddress nvarchar(MAX)
,@myPort int

AS
```

If you want to know what the ID of the newly inserted record is add

SELECT @@IDENTITY

to the end of your procedure.  e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx

You will then be able to pick this up in which ever way you are calling it be it SQL or .NET.

P.s. a better way to show you table definision would have been to script the table and paste the text into your stackoverflow browser window because your screen shot is missing the column properties part where IDENTITY is set via the GUI.  To do that right click the table 'Script Table as' --> 'CREATE to' --> Clipboard.  You can also do File or New Query Editor Window (all self explanitory) experient and see what you get.

Comment: `MyID` is not the `identity` field. The identity field is `id`.

Comment: Yes, that is true MyID is not the identity.  The Identity column is called ID.  I already updated the table definition with script.  thanks

Comment: Well in that case I've just scripted your code into a new database and run the stored procedure.  The record inserted for me.

Comment: never use `@@IDENTITY`, use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, do a google search if you need to ask why.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return back the ID within the scope, using the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` would be a better approach. I would not advice to use `@@IDENTITY`, as this can return any ID.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[sp_Test] (
  @myID int output,
  @myFirstName nvarchar(50),
  @myLastName nvarchar(50),
  @myAddress nvarchar(50),
  @myPort int
) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Dvds (myFirstName, myLastName, myAddress, myPort)
    VALUES (@myFirstName, @myLastName, @myAddress, @myPort);

    SET @myID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to populate a table in SQL SERVER you can use while statement as follows:

```
declare @llenandoTabla INT = 0;
while @llenandoTabla < 10000
begin
insert into employeestable // Name of my table
(ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GENDER, SALARY) // Parameters of my table
VALUES 
(555, 'isaias', 'perez', 'male', '12220') //values
set @llenandoTabla = @llenandoTabla + 1;
end
```

Hope it helps.